# validation for image uploading in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

```
 <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="file" name="multiple_article_logo[]" size="40" multiple/>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
 </form>

   if(isset($_FILES['multiple_article_logo']['name']) && !empty($_FILES['multiple_article_logo']['name']))
    {
        echo "Image is set";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Image is unset";
    }
```

If I am not uploading  image just I will submit the form then the output should be 'Image is unset' but it is showing that image is set so I am not understanding how to do validation for multiple image uploading.
Please solve this issue .

If i will upload image then also it is showing image is set.
So can anyone suggest me how to do validation for image uploading?

Comment: You should be using CodeIgniter's upload class. It offers all kinds of feedback as to what went wrong, and it's easy to use: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upload multiple image with validation in CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37290237/how-to-upload-multiple-image-with-validation-in-codeigniter)